# How to allocate WIFI Bandwith?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

I am having a little problem with a wireless network. I have users connected to a wireless router, and two others are connected to a repeater.

(Just to call some details the Router is an Archer C7 1750Mbit, Repeater some Netgear V3 300Mbit Internet-Connection is 100MBit/s)

Some users are experiencing severe slowdowns when connected to the repeater. However none of them are doing intensive stuff, mostly using phones to browse websites or Documents.

I have analysed this problem and I guess its not a problem in terms of internet speed. I guess its a problem of wifi bandwith, with the repeater not getting enough bandwith from the wireless router, since there are too many other devices connected.

So I wonder - is there a way to allocate wifi bandwith? And to be clear about this - i dont mean the bandwith allocation like in QoS-Protocolls, where you (as far as i understand) prioritize the cached internet data to certain clients. What I want to do is to prioritize the Repeater as a client in my wifi network, so I can make sure, he is getting his 300Mbit, no matter how many other devices are connected to the router (except of cause the loss due to signal strength etc.)

I already looked this topic up in several other places but I never found and answer to this.
So far basicly 90% of answers where "dont use wifi, use a cable" and the others where "use QoS" but as I said, this is not where my problem is (except there are dedicated QoS-Options for Wifi itself which I dont know of).

Comment: You already know the answer ... "dont use wifi, use a cable". Repeaters are awful.

Answer (score 2):

The **repeater** is the problem. By repeating you essentially halve the effective speed.

```
No repeater:
Send a packet
Acknowledgment of receipt

Repeater:
Send a packet
Resend the packet
Acknowledgment of receipt
Re-Acknowledgment of receipt
```

All that extra work congests the network. Wifi is a shared medium so only one device can transmit at a time.

What you want to do is extend your network without using the same medium to link the two devices. You can use homeplugs, ethernet or even a wireless system that isnt a repeater.

Comment: Wireless repeating without WDS is basically garbage. If it happens to work for you, great. But it often happens to not work and breaks horribly in many reasonable configurations.

Comment: I am sorry, but if have to ask this:
Is there any place on the internet, where you can ask an acutal wifi question and get an actual wifi related answer? Because everywhere I go, I geht answers like "dont use wifi", which is not helping at all ;/

Comment: @MrTony You may use wireless, but you need to not repeat. So a wireless bridge+AP will do just fine, because you're using 2x as much of the spectrum.

Comment: A brindge/AP topology would require an ethernet cable from the access point to the receiving client/switch/hub/next wireless tool. which is not possible.

Comment: @MrTony No, no cables. [Main Router]<--WLAN Ch 1--> AP <-- WLAN CH6 --> Clients

Comment: To be honest i never heared of a wifi bridge, which does not require any cables on the access point. I also did a quick research about access points and bridges, but they all showed the same result, that you have to connect clients to your bridge access point by wire.